# Fetch data from site using php and put in an array

Tags: php, arrays, fetch

```
<div>A/C:front<span style="color:red;margin:8px">/
</span>Anti-Lock Brakes<span style="color:red;margin:8px">/
</span>Passenger Airbag<span style="color:red;margin:8px">/
</span>Power Mirrors<span style="color:red;margin:8px">/
</span>Power Steering<span style="color:red;margin:8px">/
</span>Power Windows<span style="color:red;margin:8px">/
</span>Driver Airbag<span style="color:red;margin:8px">/
</span>No Accidents<span style="color:red;margin:8px">/
</span>Power Door Locks<span style="color:red;margin:8px">/</span>
</div>
```

Appears like this on website :

> A/C:front/Anti-Lock Brakes/Passenger Airbag/Power Mirrors/Power Steering/Power Windows/Driver Airbag/No Accidents/Power Door Locks/

I used `$content = file_get_contents('url');` and now i need to shift through the data.

I need to fetch each one of the options above and put them in an array or something like :

```
$option = ("A/C:front","Anti-Lock Brakes","Passenger Airbag",....);
```

Any idea how to do this using php ?

Comment: Provide full website contents or at least its URL. You might want to use DOM+XPath here.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier if you use 'simplehtmldom' or something similar.

Comment: @user2984982 Can you explain why accepted then unaccepted my answer? Perhaps I can help you more... Just because you've accepted a wrong answer to the given question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Specifically, the [`getElementsByTagName`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) function. So using your example, I suggest this. Please adjust to suit your needs:

```
// Get the contents of the URL. 
$content = file_get_contents('url');

// Parse the HTML using `DOMDocument`
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);

// Search the parsed DOM structure for `span` elements.
$option = array();    
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $span){
  $option[] = $span->nodeValue;
}

// Dumps the values in `option` for review.    
echo '<pre>';
print_r($option);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Why not use the `loadHTMLFile()` method instead? :)

Comment: hi , I'm unable to get it to work . here is the url by the way : http://www.sayuri.co.jp/used-cars/B37659-Nissan-Tiida%20Latio-japanese-used-cars

Answer (score 0):

With the source code everything is easier:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.sayuri.co.jp/used-cars/B37659-Nissan-Tiida%20Latio-japanese-used-cars');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = iterator_to_array($xpath->query('//h4/following-sibling::div')->item(0)->childNodes);
$items = array_map(function ($node) {
        return $node->nodeValue;
    }, array_filter($nodes, function ($node) {
        return $node->nodeValue != '/';
    }));
var_dump($items);
```

This gave me the following:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "A/C:front"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "Anti-Lock Brakes"
  [4]=>
  string(16) "Passenger Airbag"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "Power Mirrors"
  [8]=>
  string(14) "Power Steering"
  [10]=>
  string(13) "Power Windows"
  [12]=>
  string(13) "Driver Airbag"
  [14]=>
  string(12) "No Accidents"
  [16]=>
  string(16) "Power Door Locks"
}
```

You might want to use `array_values()` on `$items` to reset the indexes. That's all!